# unable to host multiple WebHosts in a single project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to have my app listen on multiple ports,

My main startup code;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://*:4445")
        .Build();
}
```

The additional host

```
      Host = new WebHostBuilder()
          .ConfigureServices(s => { s.AddSingleton(Session); })
          .UseKestrel()
          .UseUrls($"http://*:{Session.ProxyPort}") //5684
          .UseIISIntegration()
          .UseStartup<ProxyStartup>()
          .Build();
        Host.Start();
```

the exception

```
Message: Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:26450: address already in
```

The port is not fixed for the high port number, I also saw 28246

Some netstat stuffs; the offending port was 21975

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:21975        MyMachine:0              LISTENING
 [dotnet.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:21975        MyMachine:57398          ESTABLISHED
 [dotnet.exe]
 TCP    127.0.0.1:57398        MyMachine:21975          ESTABLISHED
 [iisexpress.exe]
```

Comment: Well, for one you can't really have multiple web hosts in a single project. However, you *can* pass multiple URLs to bind to. It takes a `string[]`, so just pass the whole array of URLs you want to bind to at once.

Comment: In theory you can. MVC views might be the biggest barrier.

Comment: the secondary hosts have no views, or controllers, or any of that stuff, they are proxies in this case. And I was able to have multiple webhost builders working in the same project; one that server and api, and one that was a dynamically configured proxy.

Answer (score 1):

in this case, the problem was tied to debugging and the project settings under debug.

there were 2 profiles, one called IIS express that the other with the name of my project that would "Launch: Project". Debugging seemed to always go to the first option (IIS EXPRESS), deleting that profile fixed my problems